# Error inserting values in SQLite Android: SQLiteException: near "BAR" while compiling: INSERT INTO My_table(FOO BAR)

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am getting this error While I am inserting data in table:

> **Error** inserting NAME='ashish' ID='1' DEPT='computer ' ROLL NO='12' DIV='c'
>
> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "NO": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO Personal_info(NAME,ID,DEPT,ROLL NO,DIV) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)

**And Inserting data lines are->**

```
public void addData()
{
    ButtonAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            boolean isInserted=myHelp.insertData("'"+EditID.getText().toString()+"'",
                                                 "'"+EditRoll.getText().toString()+"'",
                                                 "'"+EditName.getText().toString()+"'",
                                                 "'"+EditDept.getText().toString()+"'",
                                                 "'"+EditDiv.getText().toString()+"'");
            if (isInserted==true)
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Data Inserted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
            else
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Data Not Inserted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
             }
        });
    }
}



public boolean insertData(String ID,String Rollno, String Name, String Dept, String Div) {
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL1,ID);
    contentValues.put(COL2,Rollno);
    contentValues.put(COL3,Name);
    contentValues.put(COL4,Dept);
    contentValues.put(COL5, Div);
    long result = sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
    if(result==-1)
    return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

Comment: Remove space between ROLL NO

Comment: is it solve error?

Comment: yes it solved the error. thanks alot

Comment: then accept answer it will help others

Answer (score 3):

Remove space between ROLL NO it will solve you error.